How to postForEntity with response of type MultiValueMap?
This existing code compiles:
        ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap> responseEntity = null;
...
        responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(serviceURL, entity,
            MultiValueMap.class);

Compiles, but the linter is unhappy: found raw type: org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap.
If I add the types of map's key and value:
        ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> responseEntity = null;

the declaration line compiles, but the call to restTemplate.postForEntity() becomes an error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible equality constraints org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>,capture#1 of ? extends org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap.
How do I make it right -- pleasing lint in both places?

you can use a ParameterizedTypeReference for MultiValueMap<String, Object>.
        // Define the request entity (replace with your actual request)
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(/* your request body */, /* your headers */);
        ParameterizedTypeReference<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> responseType =
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>() {};

        //make call to get response
        ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> responseEntity =
                restTemplate.postForEntity(serviceURL, entity, responseType);

        // Process the response
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = responseEntity.getBody();


Wouldn't that mean some real "work" -- including string-copying -- at run-time? All for the sake of linter?..

what do you mean, I could not get, please explain in more details

It seems like your solution is not just syntactic, but would cause the program to do some extra work at runtime...

what kind of extra work here? I do see any problem it would cause? This is more generic solution but if you would like to implement your own mapping you have to write at least 10-20 lines of extra code.

Ok. I think, I finally understand, what you meant. Thanks. Yeah, this would've worked too, I suppose. But I already went ahead with my own interface (see my own answer here).

No-worky... Getting compiler error on the postForEntity-line: no suitable method found for postForEntity(java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>>,org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference<org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>>)

Creating my own little private interface solved the problem. Sigh...
    private interface MVMapSO extends MultiValueMap<String, Object> {
        // This space intentionally left blank
    }

...
        ResponseEntity<MVMapSO> responseEntity = null;
...
            responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(serviceURL, entity,
                MVMapSO.class);

